# Matlab color tile

Tags: matlab

I am trying to generate a tile image with random colors with matlab, very similar to [this](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs100M/2007fa/Graphics/RGB.pdf) example, except with random colors.

Here's my code:

Instead of a 5 by 5 tile of random colors, why do I get only one color?

```
for i=0:4
    for j=0:4% Draw tile (i,j)
        r = randi(255,1,3);
        c = [r(1)/255, r(2)/255, r(3)/255];
        fill([i i+1 i+1 i i],[j j j+1 j+1 j],c)   
    end
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add `hold on` to retain a current graph when adding new graphs, for example :

```
hold on
for i=0:4
for j=0:4% Draw tile (i,j)
    r = randi(255,1,3);
    c = [r(1)/255, r(2)/255, r(3)/255];
    fill([i i+1 i+1 i i],[j j j+1 j+1 j],c)   ;

end
end
hold off
```

[image]